# Intercambiar los valores de la primera columna con la ultima columna

Tags: java, matriz

Al imprimir mi código me sale todo lo contrario a lo que quiero, en vez de imprimirme el intercambio de columnas me imprime un intercambio de filas.

Solo quieron que me intercambie los valores de la primera columna con la última columna, ya me vi muchos tutoriales y aún no lo resuelvo.

```java
import Vectores.Modulos;
public class Problema8 {
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //definimos una matriz
       int matriz[][];
       int Filas,Columnas;
       // Lectura de filas y columnas de la matriz
       Filas =  Modulos.LeerEntero("Ingrese el tamaÃ±o de fila de la matriz : ");
       Columnas = Modulos.LeerEntero("Ingrese el tamaÃ±o de columna de la matriz");
       //creamos la matriz
       matriz= new int[Filas][Columnas];
       //lectura de los datos del vector
       for(int i=0; i<Filas; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<Columnas ; j++){
              matriz[i][j] = Modulos.LeerEntero("Ingrese valor para la matriz["+i+"]["+j+"] :");
           }
       }
       //generar una cadena con los datos de la matriz
       String cadena="";
       for(int i=0;i<Filas;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
               cadena =  cadena + "    "+matriz[i][j];
           }
           cadena=cadena+"\n";
       }
       //Intercambio de columnas
       int auxiliar;
       for(int i=0;i<matriz[0].length;i++){
           auxiliar=matriz[0][i];
           matriz[0][i]=matriz[1][i];
           matriz[1][i]=auxiliar;
       }
       String cadenas="";
       for(int i=0;i<Filas;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
                cadenas=cadenas+"  "+matriz[i][j];
            }
            cadenas=cadenas+"\n";
        }
               
       //Imprimimos las matriz
       Modulos.Imprimir("Los datos de la matriz son : \n"+cadena+"\n\n Matriz intercambiada : \n "+cadenas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Este problema me llevo a pensar un poco pero lo tengo solucionado, para que entiendas un poco mas, te voy a explicar el proceso de como intercambiar las columnas, pero antes te muestro como serian ejemplo probados:

---

```
Matriz original: 
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9
   10   11   12
   13   14   15

Matriz modificada: 
   3   2   1
   6   5   4
   9   8   7
   12   11   10
   15   14   13
```

Como vez se intercambian las columnas 1 y 3 (0,2), El código es bastante sencillo:

Se recorren las filas de la matriz, y se crea un numero auxiliar que seria la posición `i` de fila y la columna `0` (obtenemos el primer lugar en la matriz), luego se intercambia la fila actual `matriz[i][0]` por la columna que queremos intercambiar, como la fila es la misma se utiliza `i` para la fila y `columna` que es el parámetro que pasamos de la columna que elegimos cambiar, luego la columna `matriz[i][columna]` (la columna que queremos cambiar) la pasamos a la variable auxiliar que era `matriz[i][0]`

En otras palabras si tuviéramos una matriz 3x3 (se comienza a contar desde el 0) cambiamos la columna `[i][0]` por `[i][2]`, y como la variable `i` va incrementando se van cambiando todos los valores.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    int aux = matriz[i][0];
    matriz[i][0] = matriz[i][columna];
    matriz[i][columna] = aux;
}
```

Esa es la explicación del intercambio, acá te dejo mi clase que utilicé para crear esto, es diferente a la tuya porque me gusta separar todo por pequeños métodos. También he utilizado una clase que no es mía, para la entrada por teclado ya que el Scanner siempre trae problemas, se llama Parser y la podes encontrar en el siguiente enlace: https://github.com/darrensun/OJ-Solutions/blob/master/src/com/darrensun/spoj/facefrnd/Main.java

(Si te funciona el Scanner y anda todo bien para ti, pues mejor)

De todos modos el métodos de intercambio ya te lo enseñe.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        int[][] matriz;
        int filas, columnas;
    
        filas = scannerInt("Ingrese la cantidad de filas de la matriz: ");
        columnas = scannerInt("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas de la matriz: ");
    
        matriz = new int[filas][columnas];
    
        fillArray(matriz); // LLENAR ARRAY
    
        String original = arrayToString(matriz);
    
        // INTERCAMBIAMOS COLUMNAS
        intercambiarXcon0(matriz, columnas-1);
    
        print("Matriz original: " + "\n" + original + "\n" + "Matriz modificada: " + "\n" + arrayToString(matriz));
    }

    /**
     * Intercambia la posicion de 'x' columna por la columna 0.
     * El valor de la columna pasada por parametro empieza a contar
     * desde el numero 0, en una matriz 3x3 el valor de la columa a pasar es 2,
     * esto es porque del 0 al 2 hay 3 numeros. (0, 1, 2) -> 3
     * 
     * @param matriz
     * @param columna
     */
    public void intercambiarXcon0(int[][] matriz, int columna) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            int aux = matriz[i][0];
            matriz[i][0] = matriz[i][columna];
            matriz[i][columna] = aux;
        }
    
    }

    private void fillArray(int[][] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // FILAS
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) { // COLUMNAS
                array[i][j] = scannerInt("Ingresar valor en la posición ["+i+"]["+j+"] : ");
            }
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder();

    private String arrayToString(int[][] array) {
        cadena.setLength(0);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // FILAS
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) { // COLUMNAS
                cadena.append("   " + array[i][j]);
            }
            cadena.append("\n");
        }

        return cadena.toString(); 
    }

    public int scannerInt(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    
        Parser parser = new Parser(System.in);
    
        int number = 0;
    
        try {
            number = parser.nextInt();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        System.out.println(number);
    
        return number;
    }

    public void print(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }

}
```

Y otro ejemplo pero de una matriz cuadrada: (rows = columns)

---

```
Matriz original: 
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

Matriz modificada: 
   3   2   1
   6   5   4
   9   8   7
```

---

**Edit:**

Con respecto a lo ultimo preguntado en los comentarios, crea un método que retorne un entero que contenga la suma de todos los números pares de la matriz,

```
/**
 * Obtiene la suma de todos los numeros pares que
 * conforman una matriz bidimensional.
 * 
 * @param array
 * @return
 */
private int getSumaPares(int[][] array) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // FILAS
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) { // COLUMNAS
            if(array[i][j] % 2 == 0) { 
                result += array[i][j]; // si es par sumo al resultado
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Ahora en vez de intercambiar los valores de la primer columna con la segunda, simplemente remplace los números, si es lo que necesitas.

En el método de intercambiar X por 0:

```
/**
 * Intercambia la posicion de 'x' columna por la columna 0.
 * El valor de la columna pasada por parametro empieza a contar
 * desde el numero 0, en una matriz 3x3 el valor de la columa a pasar es 2,
 * esto es porque del 0 al 2 hay 3 numeros. (0, 1, 2) -> 3
 * 
 * @param matriz
 * @param columna
 */
private void intercambiarXcon0(int[][] matriz, int columna) {
    int numero = getSumaPares(matriz);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        matriz[i][0] = numero; // remplazo por la suma de todos
        matriz[i][columna] = numero; // los numeros pares que tenia la matriz.
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Bro y en el caso de que quiero hallar la suma de todos los numeros pares de la matriz y tendria que remplazar toda la primera columna con la ultima columa con el resultado de la suma como lo haria? algo asi mira  yo ingreso 3 5 8  digamos que me salio 34 la suma  entonces la matriz seria asi 34 5 34

Comment: La verdad no entendí, o al menos esto entiendo, queres recorrer cualquier matriz, sumar todos los números pares independientemente de que columna sea, mientras sea par, y remplazar los valores de la primera columna y los de la ultima por el numero que dio de la suma de los números pares que tenia la matriz, de tal modo que en una matriz 3x3 con [3,5,8,3,5,8,3,5,8] al recorrer la suma daría 8x3  teniendo en cuenta que solo se suman los números pares entonces al final tendrías una matriz de [24,5,24,24,5,24,24,5,24] ¿no?, en este caso, recorre, guarda la suma y remplaza los valores

Comment: si algo asi bro

Answer (score 0):

algo asi mira bro :

digamos que esta es la matriz que acabo de ingresar

4    - 6 -    8

2  -   7  -   9

4    - 2    - 2

las suma de los pares de toda la matriz seria 28

entonces el resultado de la suma lo remplazo en toda la primera y ultima fila

28-6- 28

28- 7- 28

28- 2 -28

Comment: Pero aquí el 9 no es par y el 2 si, pero aun así lo remplazas, bueno... supongo que no tiene que ver ya con el titulo de la pregunta, digo porque si vas a remplazar la matriz la primera columna y la segunda, no deberías intercambiar los números, seria innecesario ya que, cambiar 4 por el 8 y luego convertirlos a 28, para eso haz todo de una, obtiene la suma de los pares y remplaza la primera y ultima fila., Edito la respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

Ingresar números enteros a una matriz cuadrada de tamaño N e intercambiar los elementos de la última columna con la última fila.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/346063)